# PHP not outputting the whole value

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to convert a client's site from ColdFusion to PHP.  I am trying to replicate one of old scripts scripts where the values of a form are inserted into a mysql db.  I could not get mine to work so I tried simply echoing a value and found that it was not showing the entire value.  For example I typed in 11/13/2011 in one field and Hike in another and the output was `110`.

I'm not sure why its storing text as a number.  Even if I change it to `echo` just the Hike it outputs `0`.  Here is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">
  Event Date: <input type="text" name="eventdate" size="30" />
   Theme: <input type="text" name="theme" size="50" />
</form>
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
    $eventdate = $_POST['eventdate'];
    $theme = $_POST["theme"];
    echo $eventdate+"<br />";
    echo $theme+"<br />";
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding the fields together, not concatenating with the dot operator: `.`

```
echo $eventdate."<br />";
echo $theme."<br />";
```

PHP will attempt to coerce variables that are not the same type but joined in an operation into types that make sense (for instance, if you're attempting to add a floating point number to an integer, it will evaluate the integer as a floating point number when performing the operation).

For more information, see the documentation entry for [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and how [PHP Converts Strings to Numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: Lol I was thinking javascript.  Thanks for pointing that out!